# How to mock ISerializable classes with Moq?

Tags: .net, moq, serializable

I'm completly new to Moq and now trying to create a mock for 
`System.Reflection.Assembly` class. I'm using this code:

```
var mockAssembly = new Mock<Assembly>(); 
mockAssembly.Setup( x => x.GetTypes() ).Returns( new Type[] { 
    typeof( Type1 ), 
    typeof( Type2 ) 
} );
```

But when I run tests I get next exception:

```
System.ArgumentException : The type System.Reflection.Assembly 
implements ISerializable, but failed to provide a deserialization 
constructor 
Stack Trace: 
   at 
Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseProxyGenerator.VerifyIfBaseImplementsGet­ObjectData(Type 
baseType) 
   at 
Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.ClassProxyGenerator.GenerateCode(Type[] 
interfaces, ProxyGenerationOptions options) 
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.DefaultProxyBuilder.CreateClassProxy(Type 
classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, 
ProxyGenerationOptions options) 
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type 
classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, 
ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, 
IInterceptor[] interceptors) 
   at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory.CreateProxy[T](ICallInterceptor 
interceptor, Type[] interfaces, Object[] arguments) 
   at Moq.Mock`1.<InitializeInstance>b__0() 
   at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke(Action action) 
   at Moq.Mock`1.InitializeInstance() 
   at Moq.Mock`1.OnGetObject() 
   at Moq.Mock`1.get_Object()
```

Could you reccomend me the right way to mock `ISerializable` classes 
(like `System.Reflection.Assembly`) with Moq.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with ISerializable interface. You **can** mock ISerializable classes.

Notice the exception message:

> The type System.Reflection.Assembly
>   implements ISerializable, but failed
>   to provide a deserialization
>   constructor

Problem is, that Assembly does not provide deserialization constructor.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But could you suggest how to provide deserialization constructor using Moq in that case.

Comment: you can't - Assembly does not have any accessible constructor, and as such it's unmockable when using Moq :|

Comment: You don't need to provide a deserialization constructor to mock Assembly. You can mock the interop _Assembly class and cast to Assembly when needed.

Answer (score 7):

System.Reflection.Assembly is abstract, so you can't create a new instance of it.  However, you could create a test class which does and Mock that.

Example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomethingThatNeedsAMockAssembly()
{
    string title = "title";

    var mockAssembly = new Mock();

    mockAssembly.Setup(a => a.GetCustomAttributes(It.Is(s => s == Type.GetType("System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute")), It.IsAny())).Returns(new System.Attribute[] { new AssemblyTitleAttribute(title) } );
```

`var c = new ClassThatTakesAssemblyAndParsesIt(mockAssembly.Object);

    Assert.IsTrue(c.AssemblyTitle == title);        
    //etc

}

public class TestAssembly : Assembly
{
    public TestAssembly()
    {
    //could probably do something interesting here
    }

}`

Comment: +1 Using RhinoMocks, the `_Assembly` trick didn't work for me, and I ended up using this. Was just looking for a question to share this knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

As explained already, the problem is Assembly not exposing a deserialization constructor. This does not mean it can't be done though.

A solution using Moq as per your example would be:

```
    var mock = new Mock<_Assembly>();
    result.Setup(/* do whatever here as usual*/);
```

Note that to use `_Assembly` you will need to reference `System.Runtime.InteropServices`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a mock you could try creating a dynamic assembly and build from that.

```
var appDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
var assembly = appDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Test"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.ReflectionOnly);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to verify an embedded resource worked correctly; this worked for my situation:

```
    public class MockableAssembly : Assembly { }

    [TestClass]
    public class ApplicationSetupTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ApplyAsposeLicense_Success()
        {
            var mockAssembly = new Mock<MockableAssembly>();
            mockAssembly.Setup(a => a.GetManifestResourceStream(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockedData);

            MethodIAmTesting(mockAssembly.Object);

            mockAssembly.Verify(a => a.GetManifestResourceStream("myString"), Times.Once);
        }
```

Comment: All I needed was an assembly I could call .GetTypes() on with predictable types, and this is what fixed it for me.

Like this answer, create an inheriting class like `MockableAssembly`. Mock all the functions you need, then you can cast it back to `Assembly` and work on it again